# SlidingMenu calling difficulty

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, slidingmenu

I got in mainactivity a slidingmenu that i use for all fragments. I want to open slidingmenu when i click an image from a fragment . How is possible from my fragment to reach slidingmenu from activity , or from activity listen when on that fragment is clicked that image by id.

mainactivity.class

```
 SlidingMenu menu;
  private static MainActivity context;


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   context = this;
    menu = new SlidingMenu(context);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(false);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(context, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
   menu.setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_behind_width);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. implements OnClickListener in your Fragment
2. `public void onClick(View v){`

   ```
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.StartMenuButton: ((YourMainActivityClass)getActivity()).openMenu();


           break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a method openMenu() in your activity. And call it in your click event.